# Stop input loop when input is done | std::cin

Tags: c++, cin

I want to write a function that gets a set of integers and saves them to a vector.

To get the integers I'm using a while loop.

`Enter the vector elements: 1 2 3 4 5`

I want the loop to stop looking for input after the last element is inputted or until a non-numberis inputted, however I'm having trouble with it.

It is an assignment, so it needs to read input from std::cin.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool NumInVect(int num, std::vector<int> vect)
{
  bool numInVect = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
      if (vect[i] == num)
      {
        numInVect = true;
      }
    }
  return numInVect;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> tempVect;
  std::vector<int> finalVector;
  
  std::cout << "Enter the vector elements: ";
  
  int currVal;
  
  
  while (std::cin >> currVal)
  {
    std::cout << "-\n";
    
    if (!NumInVect(currVal, tempVect))
    {
      tempVect.push_back(currVal);
    }
    std::cout << currVal << std::endl;

  }

//the code never reaches this loop, since its stuck in the while loop
std::cout << "knak\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < tempVect.size(); i++)
    {
      std::cout << tempVect[i];
    }
  
}
```

I've tried doing multiple things like using `std::cin.eof()`/`.fail()`, `std::cin >> currVal` in the `while` loop, a `do-while` loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. Does anyone have any tips on what to look into or how to approach this?

Comment: There's nothing in your input to set `eof` or `fail` ... If you want `fail`, then you can put in garbage values like "apples" when an integer is expected. If you want to read just a _line_, then use `getline`, and pass the string to an `istringstream`

Comment: why should it stop after 5 ? because you hit enter? because it is 5 elements?

Comment: You should clarify what is the halting condition. One can assume that you want just 5 numbers, but also that '5' is a special code and you want to keep going until you read a 5, or that you want to read everything until the end of the line (which seems to be the most likely, given your code sample).

Comment: You can send the "end of stream" character to std:cin via the keyboard with `ctrl-D` (linux like) or `ctrl-z` (windows like) depending on your OS. That will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to get all the input from a given line, and add individual numbers to the vector, then you want to read a line of input into a string, then use an `istringstream` to process that line of input.

A simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> tempVect;
    std::string line;
    std::getline( std::cin, line );

    std::istringstream iss( line );
    int curVal;
    while ( iss >> curVal ) {
        tempVect.push_back( curVal );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisMM, thank you for your response. No my intention is not to read everything in the line, but read a line of integers, until there is a non-int input or no input. I've edited my post a little bit, hope that helps with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @LarioSedic, there's no way to determine that there's "no more input" unless the user puts in a special character sequence (Ctrl+Z, I think). `iss >> curVal` would "fail" on non-int input, so it would stop at that point.

Comment: Ctrl+Z Windows Ctrl+D Linux.

Comment: @ChrisMM thank you for your response. That is indeed what I figured out aswell. I appreciate your efforts into helping me <3.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a condition in your while loop so that it breaks when you want like:

```
if (temptVect.size() >= 5)
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the loop to stop looking for input after the last element is inputted or until a non-numberis inputted,

This loop should do exactly that.

```
  while (std::cin >> currVal)
  {
    std::cout << "-\n";
    
    if (!NumInVect(currVal, tempVect))
    {
      tempVect.push_back(currVal);
    }
    std::cout << currVal << std::endl;

  }
```

This test `while (std::cin >> currVal)` will fail if read does not work and exit the loop. Since `currVal` is an integer, it will fail as soon as it tries to read something that is not an integer (note space and new lines are completely ignored).

What may be the issue is that `std::cin` is buffered. You can type a long time before filling up the buffer and causing the `operator>>` to do anything. To force this operator to read you have to force a flush this is usually done by hitting `<enter>` on the keyboard.

After the buffer is flushed it will read all the numbers on the input and exit the loop if a read fails. So you need to explicitly type not a number before hitting the `<enter>`.

eg:

```
1 2 3 4 5 X<enter>
```

or:

```
1<enter>
2<enter>
3<enter>
4<enter>
5<enter>
X<enter>
```

You need that non number to force the read to fail and the loop to exit.

---

Alternatively, you could say I want to read all the numbers on one line then exit the loop.

In that case: You should read a line and the processes the line. This is only  a slight change from your above code.

```
std::string line;                     // Hold a line of text
std::getline(std::cin, line);         // Read a line of text.

std::stringstream lineStream(line);   // Convert string into stream
while (lineStream >> currValue)       // Read each integer from the stream.
{                                     // Exits when the read fails to read
                                      // a number becuase it is empty.
    // The other stuff like before.
}
```

Comment: Hi @Martin York I appreciate the effort into this comment. I also discovered that something needs to trigger the end of the input loop and that it wonn't exit by itself after entering the last integer.  I'm going to use CTRL + D. I really appreciate your response to my post <3